# preAuthorize() with hasAuthority or hasRole() not restricting access to routes

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to implement a custom database-backed userDetailsService in my spring boot project. For some reason, the admin route is available to all users despite new users only having ROLE_USER and not ROLE_ADMIN. I tried using both hasRole('ADMIN') and hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN'). I am also having trouble debugging as the getAuthorities() method print statement isn't executing, and neither is the print statement inside of loadUserByUsername. This is true even with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

It is worth noting that I was able to take a java project using OAuth2 and successfully restrict the admin route so I am wondering if this is Kotlin specific?

testcontroller:

```
@RestController
class TestController() {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @GetMapping("/api/user")
    fun getUser() : String {
        return "hello user"
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/api/admin")
    fun getAdmin() : String {
        return "hello admin"
    }
}
```

userDetails

```
@Document(collection="users")
class User (
    val principalId: String,
    val name: String,
    val email: String, 
    val service: AuthService, 
    @JsonIgnore
    @get:JvmName("getPasswordJVM")
    var password: String? = null,
    val createdDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000,
    val draftGroups: MutableList<ObjectId> = mutableListOf<ObjectId>(),
    @Id 
    val id : ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),
    var accountNonExpired: Boolean = true,
    var accountNonLocked: Boolean = true,
    var credentialsNonExpired: Boolean = true,
    var enabled: Boolean = true,
    var roles: String = "ROLE_USER"
    ) : UserDetails {
        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
            other is User && other.name == name && other.email == email
        var admin : Boolean = false
        override fun getAuthorities() : List<GrantedAuthority> {
            val authorities = mutableListOf<GrantedAuthority>()
            for (role in roles.split(",")) {
                authorities.add(SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
            }
            return authorities
        }
        override fun getUsername() : String {
            return this.name
        }
        override fun getPassword() : String {
            return this.password ?: "no password due to oauth"
        }
        override fun isAccountNonExpired() : Boolean {
            return this.accountNonExpired
        }
        override fun isAccountNonLocked() : Boolean {
            return this.accountNonLocked
        }
        override fun isCredentialsNonExpired() : Boolean {
            return this.credentialsNonExpired
        }
        override fun isEnabled() : Boolean  {
            return this.enabled
        }
    }
```

userDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService (private val userRepository: UserRepository) : UserDetailsService {

    init {
        println("user details service 13")
    }

    public override fun loadUserByUsername(s: String) : UserDetails {
        println("IN LOAD USER BY USERNAME")
        val users : List<User> = userRepository.findByName(s);

        if (users.size == 0)
            throw UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Username[%s] not found"));
        
        return users[0]
    }
}
```

securityconfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig(
    private val authenticationSuccessHandler: AuthenticationSuccessHandler,
    private val myUserDetailsService: MyUserDetailsService) {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    @Bean
    public fun override(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
                .csrf{csrf -> csrf.disable()}
                .authorizeRequests{auth -> auth
                    auth.antMatchers("/api/user").authenticated()
                    auth.antMatchers("/api/admin").authenticated()
                }
                .userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService)
                .oauth2Login()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                //\.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                // csrf token is stored in browser as cookie XSRF-TOKEN, it is send along with POST requests in request header X-XSRF-TOKEN
                // https://itnext.io/how-to-prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-of-legitime-cross-site-request-5b59a6a56808
                .and()
                .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you forgot to decorate your `SecurityConfig` with `@EnableMethodSecurity`